# Scroll down in vue in specific element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to scroll down on new appeared element in vue:

I have chat messages where I have two arrays:

```
data() {
  return {
    activeChats: [],
    openedChats: [],
    maxOpened: math.round(window.innerWidth / 300), 
  }
}
```

When I get new message and the conversation is not in active and opened arrays I  add to both and it appears on  screen because I used `v-for` on both arrays.

This everything works but I am not sure how to scroll down on div when new chat appears, I tried using refs but had no luck:

`<div class="chat" v-for="chat in openedChats" ref="chat-{chat.id}"></div>`
 Or even just chat testing with one chat opened..

And inside `axios then()` after success I said:

```
this.$refs.chat['-'+response.data.id].scrollTo(9999999,99999999);
or
this.$refs.chat['-'+response.data.id].scrollTop = 99999999;
or
this.$refs.chat.scrollTo(9999999,99999999);
or
this.$refs.chat.scrollTop = 99999999;
```

And neither worked...

Any help ? :D

Can it be done without additional library, I need no animatios just to appear at the bottom of the element...

Thanks

Comment: There's a handy library for that: https://rigor789.github.io/vue-scrollto/#/

Comment: Is there a way without additional library? :D Since I dont need smooth scrolling but just appearing at the bottom :D

Answer (score 5):

See this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/430100/

Use "watch" (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to detect changes in the message array (either from ajax or simply a button like in the example).
Set the id (or you can use ref if you prefer) based on the index of the message.
Then scroll to the last element in your array (get the last one via `array.length`).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    messages: [
      { id: 1, text: 'message' },
    ],
  },
  watch:
  {
    messages: function() {
      let id = this.messages.length;
      //takes a bit for dom to actually update
      setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById('message-' + id).scrollIntoView();
      }, 100);
      
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addMessage: function(){
      let id = this.messages.length + 1;
      this.messages.push({ id: id, text: 'message'});
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="addMessage()" style="position:fixed">
  Add message
  </button>
  <div class="message" v-for="message in messages" :id="'message-' + message.id">
    {{message.text}} {{ message.id}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I  did it on little different way :D I had two problems, my ref or id were as string, not passing as values so they were undefined. Second problem is that scroll start after array update but there is not element rendered yet so I added settimeout with 100ms and now it works. Btw I am using `document.getelementbyid('chat-'+reponse.data.id)` as el, and so I say `el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;` inside timeout